# Shader value remap - Blend Falloff

Tags: opengl, directx, glsl, shader, hlsl

I would like to know if there's a way to remap a value that goes from 0 to 1 constantly like this.

[image]

Into those values (those are examples).

[image]

This might be some function transformation but I can't find the way to do that. I've tried using a lookup texture but in my opinion this is not the best solution.
Thank you very much.

Comment: 1-3 can be done with the smoothstep function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dari said, the [**smoothstep**](http://www.fundza.com/rman_shaders/smoothstep/) function is the best solution to achieve what I need.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use a fixed number of linear gradient stops.  For example, you could have two `float4` values which define the position and value for four individual stops:

```
cbuffer CB0
{
    float4 sp; // stop positions
    float4 sv; // stop values
}

float4 main(float2 coord : COORD) : SV_TARGET
{
    float x = coord.x;
    float v = 0;
    if(x < sp.x) v = sv.x;
    else if(x < sp.y) v = lerp(sv.x, sv.y, (x - sp.x) / (sp.y - sp.x));
    else if(x < sp.z) v = lerp(sv.y, sv.z, (x - sp.y) / (sp.z - sp.y));
    else if(x < sp.w) v = lerp(sv.z, sv.w, (x - sp.z) / (sp.w - sp.z));
    else v = sv.w;
    return float4(v,v,v,1);
}
```

Example remappings are below, using increasing values greater than 1 for unused stops to avoid division by zero in the shader.  This won't affect the result, as the `lerp` will snap to the lower value anyway.

Remap1: `sp = {0,0.45,0.55,1}; sv = {0,0,1,1};`

Remap2: `sp = {0,0.1,1,2}; sv = {0,1,1,1};`

Remap3: `sp = {0,0.9,1,2}; sv = {0,0,1,1};`

Remap4: `sp = {0,1,2,3}; sv = {0,0.5,1,1};`

Of course you could use a different number of stops if you need them depending on the complexity of your gradient.